# Selenium Grid and Jenkins, upload files

Tags: selenium, jenkins, upload

How to handle upload files testing? Currently I use Selenium Grid Extra (4 machines) and when one test eq machine 04 is running want to upload file, which is not on that machine, how to create such a file or copy from hub machine? Hardcoding paths etc "C:\test\pic\01.img" it's not the best way :) because I would have to maintenance it on all machines.

Any clue? It's C# code btw

Answer (score 0):

Set the file detector to make the driver upload the file to the remote machine:

```java
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=file]"));
input.sendKeys("C:\\test\\pic\\01.img");
```

Comment: I tried like above, but I found why it's fails, I don't use RemoteWebDriver instance, but ChromeDriver instead

Comment: `ChromeDriver` extends the `RemoteWebDriver` class, so simply cast it: `((RemoteWebDriver)driver).setFileDetector(...)`